# How to attach div to bottom of textarea using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I can have multiple html textarea boxes on a web page and when any textarea receives focus, I'd like to display (or create) a div exactly underneath it. When focus leaves I want to hide (or destroy) the div. When a different textarea receives focus I want the same thing to occur. A few details:

1. The textareas can be a variety of widths and heights
2. The div attached to the underside of textarea will be fixed and unchanging, something like 200px width and 40px high. It won't change regardless of the height/width of the textarea above it.
3. The user doesn't need to interact with the div, and in fact shouldn't. It will be displaying "x of xx characters used" or something similar. It's for display only, but the contents of the div will continuously change as the user types. (hopefully this won't remove focus from the text area and hide the div)
4. Only one "div-underneath-textarea" will ever be visible at a time. Which means only 1 div need even exist. And it can be created on the fly if that's easiest.
5. Div should be created when textarea receives focus.
6. Div should be destroyed when textarea loses focus.
7. Contents of div must change each time a key is pressed.
8. The div needs to be precisely anchored just underneath the textara.

**What is the most straightforward way to achieve this with jquery?** I'm thinking that a dynamically created (and later destroyed) div could be ideal, unless it's problematic for some reason.

*I mainly need help with the dynamic div creation/destruction upon focus/blur, and the anchoring of that div to the underside of the textarea.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of all this text you could create a demo and explain the problem with 1-2 sentences.

Comment: Sorry Dekel, I'll see if I can put together that demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very simply use `insertAfter()` to insert a div after the textarea on `focusin`.  Then on `focusout` you can remove that div.  Then I'm not really sure what you want to happen when you say content of div must change each time the key is pressed.  If you want it to display the content of the textarea you can use a keyup function and just display that text or something.  If you specify what you want to happen better I can better help out.  But all that said you can do something like the following:

```js
//inserts the div under the textarea
$('textarea').on('focusin', function(){
  $('<div class="added-div">Added Div</div>').insertAfter(this);
});
//removes the added div and clears the textarea
$('textarea').on('focusout', function(){
  $('.added-div').remove();
  $(this).val('');
});
//updates the added div with textarea content
$('textarea').keyup(function () {
  var textareaContent = $(this).val();
  $('.added-div').html(textareaContent);
});
```

```css
textarea{
  display:block;
  margin:10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it as simple as I can.. see if that can be of help..
I have created template div, and then on focus I just append it after each textarea.. then on focus in/out just hide it, not distroy & recreate,, that's to expensive in my book,, I have also included simple text manipulation in that target div. cheers

```js
var templ = $('<div class="under"></div>');
// show when mouse goes in
$('textarea').on('mouseover', function(el){
  $(this).focus();
});
$('textarea').on('focus', function(el){
  // show div under that textarea
  if( ! $(this).next().hasClass( 'under') ) $(this).after( $(templ).clone() );
  $(this).next().show();
});
// hide when mouse goes out
$('textarea').on('mouseleave focusout', function(el){
  $(this).next().hide();
});
// do some stuff..
$('textarea').on('keyup', function(el){
  $(this).next().text( $(this).val().length );
});
```

```css
.ta{
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
}
.relative{ position: relative; display: inline; }
.under{
  background-color:red; color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px; left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="relative"><textarea class="ta t1"></textarea></div>
<div class="relative"><textarea class="ta t2"></textarea></div>
<div class="relative"><textarea class="ta t3"></textarea></div>
<div class="relative"><textarea class="ta t4"></textarea></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer.